# How to split StringList in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have big problem with StringList. I have text file with text like this:

```
51,179 km=Powiat Ostrzeszowski
51,179 - 61,402 km=Powiat Wieruszowski
61,402 - 64,559 km (d. DW450)=Powiat Wieruszowski
64,559 km (d. DW450)=Powiat Kępiński
```

I want to import this file and show first values, before "=" in RadioGroup. Second values after "=" i want to show on Label in moment when user clicks proper value on RadioGroup.

I would like to operate on Names and Values of StrongList.

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLih.png

In *.pas file I have:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  list: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
```

On FormCreate:

```
list := TStringList.Create;    
list.LoadFromFile('dat\a1pik.dat');
RadioGroup1.Visible := true;
RadioGroup1.Items.Clear;

for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do
    begin
        RadioGroup1.Items.Add(list.Names[i]);
    end;
```

And first values I have on RadioGroup.

I try with RadioGroup like this:

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    Label.Caption := list.Values[list.Names[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex]];
    end;
```

But doesn't work. What I do wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: There are literally thousands of articles and questions here covering that. Please make some more effort.

Comment: I just ask about RadioGroup1Click. Is this OK.

Comment: I have problem with `code`Label.Caption := list.Values[list.Names[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex]];`code` Error in Lazarus.

Comment: So read the error message, look at the code, and use your brain

Comment: valueforindex seems the way to go, if that doesn't work, you have multiple problems.